# store the current tabs after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am creating an application where i want to store the current value of tabs during postback. I want to store the current value of tab using hidden variable.

what i doing wrong?

**This is my jquery code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
        tab active.
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content.show();

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

**This my html Code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"> Content 1 </div>
    <div id="tabs-2"> Content 2 </div>
    <div id="tabs-3"> Content 3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're doing wrong depends on what you're doing at all.  I don't see any code here which indicates to the server-side code what tab is currently active, nor do I see any server-side code which renders a specific tab as active.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Wondering what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to append the tabs href to url, in that case use the following code rather than handling the click event on each tab.

```
$('.tabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        window.location.href = window.location.href.toString().split('#')[0] + ui.newTab.find('a').attr('href');
    }
});
```

Comment: sure, how do you want to contact? BTW, have a habit of marking answers  as accepted if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you postback from a control in one of the tabs, your server-side code will know what tab you came from, yes? If you want the postback to return to the same tab, set your hidden field's .Value to the appropriate index with the handler code, and have this in your jQuery ready function:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ active: <%= hfLastTab.Value %> });
```